# Style the text color in the "Currently playing" cast screen

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I cannot find a way to keep my application style below and display the text in the "Currently playing" popup screen. It's white on white as you can see in the following picture.
[image]

It seems textColor is used for the text and colorPrimary for the background. I have both white as it's used in other parts of the app. Is there a way to give a theme to this dialog only ?

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>

    <!-- Light action bar starting with Android M -->
    <!-- <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item> -->

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated, which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/gray_lighter</item>

    <!-- Customize actionbar element in white because we use a Light Theme with a strong primary color -->
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyThemeActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>

    <!--  Hide ActionBar as we use toolbar -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <!-- This is the default background color of the app. -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>

    <!--  This is the primary color of text. -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>

    <!-- Cast -->
    <item name="mediaRouteTheme">@style/CustomMediaRouterTheme</item>
    <item name="castMiniControllerStyle">@style/CustomCastMiniController</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Nop, not yet, maybe the caf sender update will fix it

Answer (score 0):

This dialog is part of the Android Media Router API. You might want to search on how to customize that dialogs style.

Comment: Thanks Leon. How could I customize the dialog style without being able to launch it myself as it's a android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider ?